# Need to add Spaces and commas in specific places

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, gawk

Need your expert advice

Input:

```
2020-01-1713:57:5888823,aJ,MO,ZXC,adf   
2020-01-1713:58:3878823,sJ,MO,AXC,Ldf    
2020-01-1713:59:1898823,DJ,LO,AZC,NDf
```

Desired Output

```
2020-01-17 13:57:58,88823,aJ,MO,ZXC,adf  
2020-01-17 13:58:38,78823,sJ,MO,AXC,Ldf    
2020-01-17 13:59:18,98823,DJ,LO,AZC,NDf
```

It will be extremely helpful if someone can help me on this.

Regards
Amit

Comment: Please use some words to describe the comma(s) that you want to add, and where they should go, so that readers aren't left counting commas and scanning your input & output on their own. Thank you!

Comment: And please include what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a guess as to what you want based on the 3 input lines you gave:

```
sed -e 's/\(^..........\)\(........\)/\1 \2,/g' in > out
```

Or, equivalently:

```
sed -e 's/\(^.\{10\}\)\(.\{8\}\)/\1 \2,/g' in > out
```

Comment: The `g` flag should not be necessary as you only expect a single substitution on each line.  Also, `cat` is needed as `sed` knows how to read from a filename given on the command line.

Comment: The desired out output states 5 commas `,`.

Comment: @terdon I used a second capture group in order to insert the comma in each line at the right place.

Comment: Oh! You're absolutely right, sorry. I hadn't noticed that the OP was also adding a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Script contents

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
txt = """
2020-01-1713:57:5888823,aJ,MO,ZXC,adf
2020-01-1713:58:3878823,sJ,MO,AXC,Ldf
2020-01-1713:59:1898823,DJ,LO,AZC,NDf
"""
for line in txt.splitlines():
    print(line[:10], line[10:])
```

Run it

```
# ./asdf
2020-01-17 13:57:5888823,aJ,MO,ZXC,adf
2020-01-17 13:58:3878823,sJ,MO,AXC,Ldf
2020-01-17 13:59:1898823,DJ,LO,AZC,NDf
```